# Export multiple-declared variables with the scope accessibility in Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, module, export

Let's say I want to have a lot of variables to be exported, for now I'm writing only few of them:

```
const
    BASE = '/src/',
    FONTS = `${BASE}/fonts`,
    CSS = `${BASE}/css`,
    JS = `${BASE}/js`;

module.exports = {
    BASE,
    FONTS,
    CSS,
    JS
};
```

The problem is, when there is too much variables, it leads to a duplicity of the code.

**Notice that I want to use previously created BASE variable to be accessible for the next variables.**

Is there some way to mention the each variable only once? Something like this (which is not appropriate way because **BASE** is not a variable in that case so it will throw an error that **BASE** is not defined):

```
module.exports = {    
    BASE: '/src/',
    FONTS: `${BASE}/fonts`,
    CSS: `${BASE}/css`,
    JS: `${BASE}/js`
};
```

**(Edit) To be more specific: Instead of declaring a variable and then exporting it in another code block, my point is to declare and export it on one place.**

Comment: You cannot reference parts of an "under construction" object from other parts of the declaration. You could however use ES2015 back-tick string templates and declare some foundation variables separately.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be exactly what you are looking for, but perhaps a better solution.

```
var o={}
o.BASE='/src/'
o.FONTS=o.BASE+'/fonts'
module.exports = o
```

As I understand it, you want to avoid using backtick syntax. This should accomplish that for you, as well as removing the extra commas on each line.